# Shredded steak for south east asian dish

Tags: asian-cuisine, steak, language, indonesian-cuisine

I have a recipe for Nasi Goreng, which calls for 1/2 lb of shredded raw rump steak.

I'm not sure how one goes about shredding steak - any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that there is a translation issue. For recipes I've used, I will cross-cut the meat into thin slices, then thinly slice the meat WITH the grain. The result will have a stringy texture - not 'bad' stringy, but stringy like good braised meat that can be shredded or 'pulled.'

This has worked for me for Korean dishes like Bulgogi and a few others.

Comment: And it helps to pop the meat into the freezer for about 30 min before you slice -- it'll firm up to make it easier to slice thinly (but be careful about freezing it for too long, or it'll be like trying to shave a brick)

Comment: Don't freeze the meat. Use a good sharp knife. That should suffice. If you don't have a good sharp knife, then you can resort to such trickery as firming up the meat in the freezer, at the price of reduced flavour, and reduced tenderness (ideally, you want to make sure the meat is freshly cut, and at room temperature when it goes into the pan. Which is impossible when cutting it cold)

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you braise it long enough it's easy to shred. But raw and shredded? Not so easy.

I would think you may be seeing a language problem--perhaps they mean "ground" instead of "shredded." Otherwise, maybe cutting it into very fine strips would work. Have you had this dish before? What was the texture of the beef in that instance? That way you'd know at least one method that would work.

Comment: Its a spicy fried rice, with lots of other things such as onions, prawns, egg etc in it.  I've previously had it with small pieces of chicken in, but this is a recipe my father has dug up.  Maybe they just mean diced beef - that would certainly work - just wondered if 'shredded steak' was a known cooking term was all.

Comment: I also think there is a problem with the translation. I am pretty sure it should read "finely sliced".

Comment: And lest we go overboard, let's not forget we're talking fried rice here--any way you like your beef is fine as long as you're able to cook it according to directions. Cubes, paper-thin slices, ground, whatever.

Comment: @ bike right on... any recipe should have room for you to adapt as needed